# How to use a picture as the cover?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, covers

For some reason, I have to use a picture as the cover of my report. I have tried `\includegraphics` ,but the result didn't satisfy me. So I turn to use`\ThisCenterWallPaper`, this is exactly what I want!  However, the content  and cover huddle together in the same page...Can anyone help me? Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\ThisCenterWallPaper{1.1}{cover.png}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{SVM}
Train Data is blabla
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `\thispagestyle{empty}\null` before `\newpage`

Comment: @David Purton The `\thispagestyle{empty}` is not necessary. One can use only `\null` before `\newpage`.